# How to change flutter text color for dark and light theme?

Tags: flutter

How to change flutter text color for dark theme and light theme, can anyone answer me ?

```
title:  Text('Kitchen Name', )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing so:

1. You can set both a `theme` and a `darkTheme` variance in your `MaterialApp` properties and having it automatically changed whenever the OS theme changes, based on the text properties that you set;
2. Or, you can manually check for the current brightness in your `Text` style's property (when the brightness is dark, the OS should be using a dark theme, and a light when it's light).

```
title: Text(
          'Kitchen Name',
          style: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white) : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
```

I'd pick the 1 since it's the most correct way of doing it.